# Get all Twitter clients from installed Applications

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm wondering if it's feasible to list out all Twitter clients that are installed into a phone. At first, I thought this could be done by matching the package name with "Twitter". But most of the Twitter clients on Android don't have 'Twitter' name in their package name.

We can fetch application list with specific permissions but that doesn't going to help me. Fetching applications with certain custom intents probably not going to help as well, and I still have to find a way to get a list of applications that handle a custom Intent.

It doesn't seem feasible but there must be some way that could at least put me close to want I want. Anyone would like to shed some light on it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is some kind of method to get "twitter client" (how we define Twitter client?).
You can fetch a list of names (the twitter clients you know) on the packages installed on devices.

```
final List<PackageInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
final String separator = ";";
final String separatorVersion = "-";

//Log.i("Package list", "num:+"+apps.size());
for (PackageInfo infoApp : apps) {
    for (TwitterClient tr : mapTwitterClient.values()) {
        if (infoApp.packageName.contains(tr.getPackageName()) ) { //it's a Twitter client this package?
            if (!twitterClients.equals("")) {
                twittersClients += separator;
            }
            twitterClients += tr.getCommonName()+separatorVersion+infoApp.versionName;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to create the class TwitterClient which just have 2 properties(packageName and commonName) and his getters/setters.

And fill map with all TwitterClient you know (Ex: `new TwitterClient("com.twitter.android","Twitter official")` );

```
private static final HashMap<String, TwitterClient> mapTwitterClient
```

This method it's hard process so use smartly.